# C# memory after fixed and the Garbage Collector

Tags: c#, pointers, garbage-collection, unsafe

I am reading bytes from a binary file with `BinaryReader.Read` and using the `fixed` statement to 'convert' the bytes into a struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
unsafe struct MyStruct
{
    // some variables.. too many to list
    public fixed Byte Software[32];
    public UInt16 FC_Day;
    public UInt16 FC_Year;
    public UInt16 Header_Size; 
    public UInt32 Offset_to_Data;
    // more variables.. too many to list
};
```

Then later in Main:

```
byte[] ReadBytes = new byte[227];
MyStruct* Header;
InFile.Read(ReadBytes, 0, 227);
fixed (byte* bHdrPtr = &ReadBytes[0])
{
    Header = (LASHeader*)bHdrPtr;
    //now Header and ReadBytes occupy the same memory
}
```

At this point any changes to `ReadBytes` changes `Header` and visa versa. As I understand it the `fixed` statement exempts the pointer from moving whilst in the `fixed` block, but will the structure and bytes now *permanently* occupy the same memory or will internal memory management move/shuffle the addresses separately? i.e. Can I trust the structure after the `fixed` block to point to the same meaningful memory and not become random bytes or all 0's?

Previously I was declaring both the `bytes[227]` and the `MyStruct` and using `Buffer.BlockCopy` to copy the bytes from the array to the structure.. this is horribly inefficient requiring double the memory and a block copy each time new bytes are read so I would prefer to recast the bytes like I have done in C++ to save memory and hopefully speed up the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but will the structure and bytes now permanently occupy the same
>   memory

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement) for `fixed` state:

> After the code in the statement is executed, any pinned variables are
>   unpinned and subject to garbage collection. Therefore, do not point to
>   those variables outside the fixed statement. The variables declared in
>   the fixed statement are scoped to that statement

As such, no - the change is not **permanent** - it is scoped *only* to within the `fixed` statement.